# JavaScript for objects with same id

Tags: javascript, select, this

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
//forLoop (users)
    <b>UserName</b>
    <select id = "select-dropdown" onclick="showOptions()">
    </select>
//endof forLoop
```

JavaScript:

```
function showOptions(){
var select = document.getElementById("select-dropdown");
var response = "option__option";

var optionList = response.split("__");
var size = optionList.length;

for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    select.innerHTML += "<option>" + optionList[i] + "</option>";
}
}
```

When I run the code I have a list of ten users with 10 select items but the drop-down option works only for the first user.

I'm guessing that the problem is caused by the same ID for all the users and I should use something like *this* but I can't find any specific answer on the internet

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with the same ID in the same html page. If you have a similar situation, your scripts referring to those elements may not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID's need to be unique. You cannot use the same ID twice on the same page.

Give them a class instead:

```
<select class="select-dropdown">
```

Consider using [jQuery as your Javascript framework](http://jquery.com/) rather than trying to do things yourself. It'll save you much time and energy.

In jQuery you'll be able to obtain all of your select elements with a simple selector:

```
var selectElements = $('.select-dropdown');
```

You'll also be able to get rid of your inline event attachment that you're curently using. Attaching events in the HTML is bad practice.

Using jQuery:

```
    $('.select-dropdown').click(function(){
       // This refers to the dropdown that is currently clicked.
       var currentSelect = $(this); 

       // Code here that executes when the dropdown is clicked.
    });
```

**UPDATE**
Here's an example of getting the current select element, the old skool way: http://jsfiddle.net/G2ZuE/

Comment: Thank you! I know about jQuery but I'm trying to do this in JavaScript for some reason. Let's say that I would use a class. In this case, how can I insert some code in that specified innerHTML without using getElementByClass

Comment: The way you've done it, you already have access to the select element through the this keyword. You don't need to go finding it on the page again.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign the same ID to different html elements, you can append a suffix to the select ID and cycle them by ID prefix or by common css class (and if you can use a lib like JQuery or MooTools it will be definitely more straightforward).

See [here for a pure-javascript sample implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/LHc32/).

```
var users = document.getElementById("users"); 
var dpDowns = users.getElementsByTagName("select"); 
for (var i = 0; i < dpDowns.length; i++) { 
    //alert(dpDowns[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your guess was correct. In addition you should put event handling in the JS not in the HTML. The following code should do it.

The HTML:

```
    <select class="someClass">
    </select>

    <select class="someClass">
    </select>

    <select class="someClass">
    </select>
```

The JavaScript

```
    // grab selects
    var selects = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
    var optionsAsString = "option__option";
    var options = optionsAsString.split("__");
    for(var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
      selects[i].onclick = function() {
        // clear initally
        this.innerHTML = "";
        var select = this;
        for(var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
          this.innerHTML += "<option>" + options[j] + "</option>";
        }
      }
    }
```

I hope this helps.